# Question related to counting primes with modulos

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am trying to count the primes via some sort of sieves with modulos. For example:

$N - (N \mod 2 - N \mod 3 - N \mod 5 ...) + (N \mod 6 + N \mod 10 + N \mod 15 +\dots)$

And so I would imagine that the ratio of second part with prime combination would be equal to the first part since the ratio of primes to normal numbers goes to zero. Is that the correct assumption? because im running the script and the second part is larger than the first part

this is the chart I am getting the orange line is the prime combos and blue line is the reciprocals of primes[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be accounting for all square-free integers (e.g. $N \bmod 14$ seems to be missing), and for $N \bmod n$ perhaps you need to take into account the number of primes dividing $n$.

---

Perhaps the formula

$$\pi(x)=-\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\log_2(x)} \mu(m) \sum\limits_{n=1}^{x^{1/m}} \mu(n)\, \nu(n) \left\lfloor \frac{x^{1/m}}{n}\right\rfloor\tag{1}$$

where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function (see [OEIS entry A008683](https://oeis.org/A008683)) and $\nu(n)$ is the number of distinct primes dividing $n$ (see [OEIS entry A001221](https://oeis.org/A001221)) provides some insight.

---

Formula (1) above is equivalent to

$$\pi(x)=\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\log_2(x)} \mu(m)\ k\left(x^{1/m}\right)\tag{2}$$

where

$$k(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2(x)} \pi\left(x^{1/n}\right)=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \mu(n)\, \nu(n) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor\tag{3}$$

is the number of prime-powers less than or equal to $x$.

Comment: Sorry yeah I did include N mod 14 in my script. I think what happens is when numbers become larger and they have for example 4 divisors then in the first term it will count as 4 but in the second term itll be counted as 6. Like for example 2*3*5*7 will be divided by 2, 3, 5, 7 in the first term but it would be like 2*3, 2*5, 2*7, 3*5, 3*7 5*7 in the second term so it kind of overtakes the first one. I thought it would have always been smaller though.